# Comparing strings passed through socket UTF8

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have an interesting problem here.

First I have a UI in Java. The UI at one point connects to a rpi4 on the network via a socket. From there data is sent over the socket using .writeUTF(string).

On the rpi4 side, I'm running a simple Python 3 script. Its sole purpose is to spit out anything that comes over the socket and it does. But before it does I use recv.decode('utf-8') to decode the string.

From Java I send "fillOpen"

In python after decoding it prints "fillOpen"

The issue:

Performing a string compare in the python script on the decoded string always results in false. I have set it up as such:

```
Command = recv.decode('utf-8')
If Command == "fillOpen":
  #Do work
```

I have also tried to not decode the string and compare to an encoded string. As such:

```
Command = recv
FillOpenCommand = 
("fillOpen").encode('utf-8')
If fillOpenCommand == Command:
#Do work
```

None of these comparisons result in true.

I have read that the Java writeUTF is a UTF8 encoding but slightly "different"?

Can I adjust the .writeUTF to work with the Python 3 decoder? Is there an alternative for sending data that can be parsed then have a string comp applied via Python that would work?

Thank you guys.

Comment: have you checked what character are there is the string you receive? Maybe there's some trailing whitespace?

Comment: I have tried this. After the string has been decoded to replace all \t '  ' '\n' with ' ' but to no avail.

Comment: What is this writeUTF method in Java that you use? This one? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)

Comment: Can you show the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#repr) of the value  read from the socket, before any actions are performed on it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the `writeUTF` method as defined in the Java `DataOutput` interface:

The output from `writeUTF` starts with two bytes of length information. You can skip it or you can use it to make sure you have received a complete message.

The easiest thing to do is to skip it:

```
Command = recv[2:].decode('utf-8')
```

If your commands are simply ASCII and don't contain things like user input, emojis, musical notation, this is good enough. Otherwise, you still have a problem. The way `writeUTF` handles "surrogate pair" characters is not valid "utf-8", and `decode('utf-8')` will throw a `UnicodeDecodeError`. If I were you, in this case I would **stop using writeUTF** and start using methods that produce standard UTF-8 encoded data.